Purpose of sleeve on sledge hammer handle
What is the intended purpose of the wedge-shaped sleeve on this sledgehammer handle near the head?

POWERFIST 12 lb Sledge Hammer

It is so the part in question takes the brunt of over strikes where the handle in that spot will take damage over time.
It is in essence a handle protector.
I have seen handles that were nearly chipped away slowly over the years where the head was about ready to fall off.


@keshlam Yeah, after some time driving wedges into huge logs, I improvised this using pipe insulation foam and some zip ties. Over stiking and hitting steel with wood handle was not good at all for the sledge.

Is the sledge image one you took on your own? If you found that someplace you need to provide a link in the message as to where that came from.

@MichaelKaras , Ecnerwal edited my post and added the picture. I thought it was a nice touch. His picture description was, he did have a sledgehammer with a bad handle, but he had a splitting maul. It reminds me of the one I had back in the day.

Jack is absolutely right. I spent much of the 80s as a kid splitting fir and pine for my family's home heating needs with a maul and wedges. As an 85 lb. stringbean I missed often. As a carpenter I've used sledges countless times, and while I have pretty good marksmanship these days, misses still happen.
All that is to point out that such sleeves have a secondary purpose: They reduce recoil forces on the operator's hands and wrists. They can act as both an impact blunter and a vibration dampener. This dramatically reduces felt shock in joints and bones. Older folks who know how to work with their bodies understand.

Supporting link:  The handle...is fitted with a thermoplastic protector that reduces vibration and protects against failed blows..
